# iOS Settings Bundle with items that appear only in Debug builds

Tags: ios

I have user setting that I want to have available in settings, but only if it is a debug build, or perhaps it is one of two separate targets.

In the settings bundle, I have the item in Root.plist, but I want it to only be visible if it is a debug build.

Is there any way to make something conditional in the settings bundle?

I know that I can use separate settings bundles for two different build targets, but that would require me to maintain two separate settings bundles, and that seems pretty messy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a Settings.plist with everything in it, then add a build step for the target where you don't want to expose one of the settings. In that build step, use [PlistBuddy](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/PlistBuddy.8.html) to remove the setting you don't want.

This has the advantage of letting you use the great tools Xcode provides for editing your plist, while remaining DRY.

Answer (score 0):

In you application delegate, read the plist and put into a dictionary. Then use a compile time flag for the DEBUG build, which turns on some code that adds or modifies the plist turned dictionary. From then on don't access the plist directly, interface to the dictionary through a method in the app delegate.

EDIT: write some command line level software to take your standard plist, and based on the build configuration, change it, then output it back as a plist that then is copied into your app bundle, as a build phase. You may be able to do this with standard system cli functions, or if you do it in a custom mac cli program, its a simple thing to construct.

Comment: I should have been more specific-- I want the setting to NOT appear in the device settings if you are building one way, and it want it to appear in the device settings if you are building it in another way.

Comment: Right - you cannot dynamically change the plist, but if you read it into a mutable object first, you can programmatically modify it based on code that is conditionally compiled into your app: myAppPlist = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:...];" Obviously this will only affect values read by your code, not iOS.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there is no way to put conditionals (or, for that matter, any form of code) in the settings bundle.  You could create an in-app settings page that is only displayed in debug mode or something of the sort though.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your schema to run a script as one of the build pre-actions. The script can generate Root.plist and and include the extra settings or not as appropriate. Although you could use whatever language you want for your generator script (Ruby, Tcl, Forth,...), I would just use the C Pre-processor.

Specifically,

1. Create a file, Root.plist.orig which includes all the regular settings. Include your extra settings wrapped in `#ifdef DEBUG` and `#endif`
2. Create a build run-script pre-action in your schema. The script should consist of a shell command to run the pre-processor. So something like (I don't have the details 100% correct):  `cpp -DDEBUG Root.plist.orig > Root.plist`